# Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I am using Xcode 7.3. I have already put Playground and Frameworks in same workspace and have built the framework. I am still getting this error

```
Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols:  
_RestofireVersionNumber
```

[image: Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols]

How to resolve this ?

Comment: I seem to be experiencing this with both CocoaPods and Carthage. It seems to be related to your framework including dependencies. Remove those dependencies and it works fine, but obviously that isn't a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `.podspec` for your library, you can use [cocoapods-playgrounds](https://github.com/neonichu/ThisCouldBeUsButYouPlaying) to generate a Playground which should work.

```
$ gem install cocoapods-playgrounds
$ pod playgrounds Restofire.podspec
```

It looks like the plugin has tentative support for Carthage projects too.

The plugin creates a new folder inside your project folder with the following structure:

```
RestofirePlayground
├── Podfile
├── Podfile.lock
├── Pods
│   ├── Alamofire
│   ├── Headers
│   ├── Local\ Podspecs
│   │   └── Restofire.podspec.json
│   ├── Manifest.lock
│   ├── Pods.xcodeproj
│   └── Target\ Support\ Files
│       ├── Alamofire
│       ├── Pods-TidalPlayground
│       └── Restofire
├── Restofire.playground
├── Restofire.xcodeproj
└── Restofire.xcworkspace
```

All that remains after generating the Playground is to build the `RestofirePlayground` scheme then you're good to go.